# Generate average for a chunks of data, when a chunk is not divisible with the size of my data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a function that averages a certain fixed-size subsets of my (column) vector.

I am doing it by reshaping my vector into the prescribed sized chunks, and then using the mean function on each row.

For example

```
A = rand(10,1)
B = reshape(A,[],2)
A = mean(B,2)
```

However, if my vector is not divisible with the size of my chunk, reshape will spit out on error. How can I account for that such that it will just throw away the rest of my original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A=rand(10,1)
chunkSize = 2

C = chunkSize *floor(size(A,1)/chunkSize )   %// Find the biggest subset that will be divisible by chunkSize 
M=mean(reshape(A(1:C), chunkSize, []))       %// Use reshape as you did but leaving off the extra end bits
M = [M, mean(A(C+1:end))]                    %// then find the mean of the extra end bits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try` and `catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to treat this. then in the `catch` part you can either ignore or add  elements to `A` that conserve the mean of the remaining chunk. In Matlab's [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) there are good examples how to do these things. Here an example for that:

```
A=randi(10,11,1);
chunk_size=4;

try
    B = reshape(A,chunk_size,[]);
catch err
    if (strcmp(err.identifier,'MATLAB:getReshapeDims:notDivisible'))
        A2=A;
        A2(end+1:chunk_size*ceil(size(A,1)/chunk_size )) = mean( A(chunk_size*floor(size(A,1)/chunk_size )+1:end));
        B = reshape(A2,4,[]);
        C=mean(B,1);
    end

end
```

*I've initially added `A2` to `A`   for debugging...*